# Set root permissions for users for www-data group

Tags: google-cloud-platform

We can't deploy the tasks to the production because of a lack of permissions on the server.
None of our users can modify, delete or upload files on the server. And to be more exact we need to be able to do that actions in www-data group on the server. Because the project is in this group.
How can we set root permissions for users for www-data group to get full access?

Comment: How are you uploading files to the server? Which user identity are you using? Typically, the Apache website directory is owned by root. There are many documents on the Internet covering how to set up a web server. The exact details depend on OS, web server software, tools that you are using, etc.

Answer (score 2):

Give writing rights/permissions for *www-data* and add yourself to *www-data* group.

The directory with site: *public_html*, user that will upload: *user1*

# at the beginning means you're root. If not use *sudo*.

```sh
# chown -R whatever-user.www-data public_html
# chmod g+w public_html
# usermod -a -G www-data user1
```